# Disable Raspi-Config

Tags: boot, ssh, raspi-config, init.d

I am able to view the output of the boot sequence of the RPi, however, I have no USB keyboard and so cannot get past the raspi-config screen. I also do not have a router, I have only a link-local ethernet connection from my laptop to the RPi.

I have mounted the SD card in a linux VM and looked through the rc.local file, init.d etc. and haven't seen where raspi-config is called.

How does one go about:

1. Disabling raspi-config
2. Enabling SSH?

**Edit:** so I eventually found the raspi-config file in /usr/bin, and looking at the code I see it has an interactive=True option. I chmodded it to writeable in my VM and changed this option to false. The result: kernel panic on the RPi - unable to mount VFS root filesystem. This is a bit depressing as I was under the impression I could modify the filesystem on the SD card without ruining the image. Any ideas on this would be appreciated.

Comment: ssh should be enabled by default, as is DHCP.  Do you give the Pi an IP address from your machine?

Comment: Give a look at do_ssh () and disable_raspi_config_at_boot() for some hint.

Answer (score 4):

I ended up getting around this problem by doing the following:

1. Running a DHCP server on the laptop
2. Connecting the RPi to the ethernet port directly
3. Granting the RPi an IP through the DHCP server
4. SSHing into it
5. Manually running the raspi-config program from the terminal
6. Selecting "Finish" (otherwise it keeps popping up).

Comment: good work. did you then check what files have been changed so you never need to do it again in the future.

Answer (score 0):

If using a MAC (probably similar with windows/*nix) with ethernet direct connection:

- Connect directly to pi with patch ethernet cable
- Settings -> Sharing -> Turn on internet sharing to thunderbolt ethernet
- run “arp -a” to find IP of the pi
- telnet to 22 or ssh to it to validate
- If not working, reboot mac or find networking restart command

Source: http://www.interlockroc.org/2012/12/06/raspberry-pi-macgyver/

Using a serial cable to the serial gpio pins:

You can connect the Pi to a PC using a USB-serial cable, or (if it has an RS232 port) a level-converter circuit - see above for details. When this is done, you will need to set up a terminal emulator program on your PC as described below.

Console serial parameters
The following parameters are needed to connect to the Pi console, and apply on both Linux and Windows.

Speed (baud rate): 115200
Bits: 8
Parity: None
Stop Bits: 1
Flow Control: None

Source: http://elinux.org/RPi_Serial_Connection, http://www.interlockroc.org/2012/12/06/raspberry-pi-macgyver/